# How to change tile background on mouse over in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tile, mahapps.metro

Using the code provided in this post:

[lighten background color on button click per binding with converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126224/lighten-background-color-on-button-click-per-binding-with-converter)

I have written the following code to change the background of a MahApps Tile on MouseOver:

```
<local:ColorLightConverter x:Key="colorLightConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="aaa" TargetType="mah:Tile">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource colorLightConverter}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The color light converter is the same as written in the post mentioned and the style is used on the Mahapps Metro Tile. The code does not work, because the tile flickers on MouseOver. Also, placing a breakpoint inside the converter, I saw that it is not reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You set a key to the style. Did you also set the style to the tiles using that key? How are you setting the style?

Comment: @Siderite Zackwehdex The style is set as follows:  <mah:Tile Style="{StaticResource aaa}" x:Name="systemTile" Title="System" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ...

Comment: why is the binding Mode OneTime?

Comment: @Siderite Zackwehdex According to the post I've mentioned, as I understand it, this mode should stop the flickering. I've tried all modes, and even without any mode set it still flickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem with the Tile control. It never enters the Converter code because TemplatedParent is null. When I changed the RelativeSource to `AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}` as it was in my case, the flickering went away and the breakpoint in the converter was reached. You can check if this is the case with you by adding to the Binding `FallbackValue=Red` in which case the color on mouse over will be Red for a faulty binding.

Here is my working XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:ColorLightConverter x:Key="colorLightConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="aaa" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Converter={StaticResource colorLightConverter},FallbackValue=Red}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Background="DarkGoldenrod">
        <mah:Tile Title="Hello!" Style="{StaticResource aaa}" 
                    TiltFactor="2"
                    Width="100" Height="100" 
                    Count="1" x:Name="tile">
        </mah:Tile>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource aaa}">Test</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: After adding FallbackValue=Red, indeed the tile changed to red on MouseOver. So the problem is related to the tile? Is there any fix for it?

Comment: No, the problem is related to the binding. Use another way for the relativesource and it will work. What type of control hosts the Tiles? It is related to the Tiles only because a TextBox doesn't flicker if the binding fails, but the fact that the binding doesn't find the background value is the problem.

Comment: I understand. The tile is hosted by a StackPanel. I'm using this code: Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Mode=OneTime, FallbackValue=red, Converter={StaticResource colorLightConverter}}", but I still get the red background and the breakpoint isn't reached (binding problem). And if I remove fallback value, the flicker is still there.

Comment: Does the StackPanel have a Background color set? Also, remove the binding Mode, it is confusing.

Comment: You can also use ElementName in the binding, if you know the name of the control you want to take the color from.

Comment: No. But I added a background color and the result is the same. I have removed the binding mode.

Comment: In my style I also added a background setter with a color. It seems the Tile doesn't register IsMouseOver in the areas with no content unless it has a background set.

Comment: And using the ElementName I still get the red background. I mention that, in this case, without Mode=OneTime I get stackoverflow exception (like it's described in the post mentioned).

Comment: I've updated the answer with my working XAML, which works with AncestorType and no Mode. I've tested with ElementName and it worked as well. I believe setting the Background for the Tile is essential.

Comment: Thank you for your code. It works perfectly for the text box, but the tile still flickers. If I set a background color for the tile (e.g., Background="AliceBlue"), then it will not work at all. If I leave the fallback value, then both textbox and tile turn red. I observed that if I mode the cursor over the tile content, then the flicker will stop.

Comment: Set it in the style! Like in the example.`<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>` In order to override the background in a style trigger, you need to set the background in the style as well. A style trigger will not override an inline property setting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the result is the same.

Comment: Come to a chat room, this is getting too long: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109369/how-to-change-tile-background-on-mouse-over-in-wpf

Comment: It seems I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Well, then I can't really help you anymore. I've used the latest NuGet for Tile and nothing more than the XAML in the answer and I cannot reproduce the flicker anymore. You may want to update the question with more of the XAML so maybe someone finds the problem.

Comment: Please find my detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

OK. So this is the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<mah:MetroWindow 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF"
    xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF.Properties"
    xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" 
    x:Class="NQR_GUI_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="600" Width="800" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" TitlebarHeight="28"
    GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ShowIconOnTitleBar="False" Icon="Pictures/icon.ico"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorLightConverter x:Key="colorLightConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="aaa" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Converter={StaticResource colorLightConverter}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="DarkGoldenrod">
    <mah:Tile Title="Hello!" Style="{StaticResource aaa}"
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="100" Height="100" 
                Count="1" x:Name="tile">
    </mah:Tile>
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource aaa}">Test</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="NQR_GUI_WPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF"
         xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="settingsIcon" UriSource="Pictures/settings1_unpressed.png" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is the color converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         Color color = (Color)value;
         System.Drawing.Color darkColor = System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Dark(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B), 0.1f);
         return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(darkColor.A, darkColor.R, darkColor.G, darkColor.B);
     }
```

I am using MahApps 1.2.4.0.

Comment: Your converter is wrong. It returns a System.Drawing.Color, not a System.Windows.Media.Brush. Replace last line with: `return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));`

Comment: @Siderite Zackwehdex This solution replaces, on MouseOver, the color of the tile with the color of the host control (in this case a StackPanel). Is it possible to replace the initial tile color with a darker one (that was the purpose of the color converter)?

Comment: Sure, just add the binding in the style's initial setter, just like in the trigger's setter.

Comment: @Siderite Zackwehdex I can't figure out how to properly write the binding. Basically, I want to be able to: set the tile's background in the designer view, then apply this style to the tile and, during runtime, on MouseOver to see its background darken (highlighting the tile) and return to the initial color when the mouse exists the tile (the host control's background shouldn't influence this logic). Here is my code (which does not work): <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" /> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is part of the question. This is not an answer. Please put the entire question in the question, not in answers. Thank you.