# How To Lighten/Darken Tile Background Color On Mouse Over?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tile, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps framework and I have the style (see [How to change tile background on mouse over in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675002/how-to-change-tile-background-on-mouse-over-in-wpf)) for highlighting a tile on MouseOver.

```
 <local:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
 <Style x:Key="highlightedTile" TargetType="mah:Tile">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, Mode=OneTime, FallbackValue=red}" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

The color converter code is:

```
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] temp = StringToByteArray(value.ToString().Substring(1, 8)); // Remove #
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);
        System.Drawing.Color darkColor = System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Dark(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B), 0.1f);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(darkColor.A, darkColor.R, darkColor.G, darkColor.B));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

        byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
        }

        return arr;
    }

    public static int GetHexVal(char hex)
    {
        int val = (int)hex;
        //For uppercase A-F letters:
        return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
        //For lowercase a-f letters:
        //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 87);
        //Or the two combined, but a bit slower:
        //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : (val < 97 ? 55 : 87));
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to:

1. set the tile's background in the designer view; DONE
2. then apply this style to the tile; DONE
3. during runtime, on MouseOver to see its background darken (highlighting the tile) and return to the initial color when the mouse exists the tile (the host control's background shouldn't influence this logic). **NEED HELP**

My code works only if I set the non-highlighted background color in the style (in this case, "Purple"). Without setting this color in the style (removing the first line), the code only works with the default blue background color of the tile (if I set the color in MainWindow.xaml, then the Converter isn't even triggered, which I verified using a breakpoint). Initially I used this binding, but does not work:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it what I'm asking actually achievable?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with MahApps, but wouldn't targettype generally be something closer to `TargetType="controls:Tile"` and the value binding not require a relativesource, as well as the property being just Background as opposed to Background.Color?

Comment: @ChrisW. TargetType works both with Control and controls:Tile. I've tried this, but does not work: <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background}" />. The tile code is: <mah:Tile Style="{StaticResource highlightedTile}" Background="SeaGreen" x:Name="systemTile".../>. My code above, except the first Setter Property, works only if I do not explicitly set a tile background color.

Comment: @jstreet Thank you! However I noticed that this code works only if I do not set a tile background color. If I leave the default blue color it works, but if I set a background color (in MainWindow.xaml), e.g., `Background="Purple"`, then it doesn't even trigger the converter (verified using a breakpoint).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to bind a color to a brush property.  Architecturally, the Tile is just a Button, and Background is supposed to be a brush.  Does the ColorConverter return a Brush?

Comment: I think I know what's going on with the color then...  If you set an explicit value to a property that has a OneWay binding, then the binding is destroyed.  Try setting the binding with `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: I will say that the code you have listed does not work for me.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Hi! The color converter returns a brush: `System.Drawing.Color darkColor = System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Dark(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B), 0.1f);
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(darkColor.A, darkColor.R, darkColor.G, darkColor.B));` I set the `Mode=TwoWay` and it does not work (also verified using `FallbackValue=red`). Again, the problem is that want this highlighting behavior to work even when I set the the background color in designer. See my edited message for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to override the style for the Tile and use your converter at the ControlTemplate triggers.

[image]

The following XAML source works with the latest source of MahApps, which is also available vie NuGet (pre-release).

```
<local:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
<Style x:Key="CustomTileStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Tile}}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:Tile}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Tile">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding CountFontSize}"
                                            Text="{TemplateBinding Count}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalTitleAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalTitleAlignment}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                                <AccessText Margin="3"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding TitleFontSize}"
                                            Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_HoverBorder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            Opacity="0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush), Mode=OneWay, Converter={x:Static converters:IsNullConverter.Instance}}" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_HoverBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                                                CenterY="0.5"
                                                ScaleX="0.98"
                                                ScaleY="0.98" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".55" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem. However, I had to write `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` instead of `HorizontalTitleAlignment` and `VerticalTitleAlignment`, because of "member not recognized or not accessible error". Also, I had to remove first MultiDataTrigger condition, because of "namespace prefix converters not defined" error.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I just copied this from the latest source (pre-release) of MahApps.